# math expression form

Tags: formatting

in fact I want to have a good expression form. In the code  below, when you compile it, the arrow isn't on the full term  and also the exp is bigger than the H_x or H_y term ? How can I enhance the form of the expression

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}

\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,nccmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
%%\usepackage{caption} % is loaded automatically by 'subcaption'
\usepackage{lscape,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % centered 'p' col.
%%\usepackage{natbib} % is loaded automatically by elsarticle doc class
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{framed}  % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}}

%% Load the next two packages *last*:
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
blablablablablablablabla
$\vec{V}_x$=$\frac{H_z}{3}$$\exp(jK)$  \: \: $\vec{V}_y$=$\frac{H_z}
{3}$$\exp(jm)$
\end[document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\vec` there is `\overrightarrow`, but I think it looks ugly in this context (you almost need `\overrightarrow{V}_{\!\!x}` to correct for the subscript placement).  To make fractions all of same size, there is `\dfrac`; however, that destroys the natural line spacing for inline math, such as you have provided.

Comment: please next time try to make a more minimal example, you could delete almost all of the packages here as they are unrelated to the question. Also you can not possibly get correct math typesetting if you do `$x$=$y$` instead of the far more natural `$x=y$` why are you setting the `=` in text mode and not in math mode?

Comment: What does = provides in math mode ??

Comment: Anyway Thanks to both of you Steven and David

Comment: Mico its \end{document}  just a fast typing

Comment: @twimo "fast typing" isn't really an excuse, it means you didn't test the code before posting it (and you can still edit the question to fix it)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your question about `=` surely equality is the most canonical math operator, it should be set in math mode, using the math fonts, but you were setting it in text mode (which might sometimes accidentally use the correct font, but will never give it the correct spacing)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The cramped form is forced by the markup used, if you mark up the math expressions as intended you get more space, you can also use an expanding over-arrow and `\dfrac` to get display style fractions, but really such an expression is too tall to be set in inline math and looks better set in display math style as in the final version.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
blablablablablablablabla
$\vec{V}_x$=$\frac{H_z}{3}$$\exp(jK)$  \: \: $\vec{V}_y$=$\frac{H_z}
{3}$$\exp(jm)$

\bigskip

blablablablablablablabla
$\vec{V}_x=\frac{H_z}{3}\exp(jK)$   \quad $\vec{V}_y=\frac{H_z}{3}\exp(jm)$

\bigskip

blablablablablablablabla
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
$\vec{V}_x=\frac{H_z}{3}\exp(jK)$   \quad $\vec{V}_y=\frac{H_z}{3}\exp(jm)$

\bigskip

blablablablablablablabla
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
$\vec{V}_x=\dfrac{H_z}{3}\exp(jK)$   \quad $\vec{V}_y=\dfrac{H_z}{3}\exp(jm)$

\bigskip

blablablablablablablabla
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
\[\vec{V}_x=\frac{H_z}{3}\exp(jK)  \qquad \vec{V}_y=\frac{H_z}{3}\exp(jm)\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose to use the `esvect` package, which defines 8 arrow tips for extensible arrows, and takes care of  vectors with subscript, and the `\mfrac`  command from `nccmath`. I took the opportunity to simplify your code: why does each element of a formula have its own pair of `$`?

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}

\begin{document}

blablablablablablablabla\enspace 
$\vv*{V}{x} = \mfrac{H_z}{3}\exp(jK)$ \: \: $\vv*{V}{y} = \mfrac{H_z}
{3}\exp(jm)$

\end{document}
```

[image]